# //@attrib vs //name/@attrib in C#

Tags: c#, xpath, xmldocument, selectsinglenode

On the XML below, I'm using the `SelectSingleNode` of `XmlDocument` to pull out the result value.

```
evtASxml.SelectSingleNode(@"//@value").Value
```

returns the value of the first "value."

```
evtASxml.SelectSingleNode(@"//Result/@value").Value
```

raises a null exception.

Could someone explain what's going on?

```
 <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2" Guid="{f00f00-f00-f00f00-f00-f00f00f00}" /> 
  <EventID>30</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>30</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x4000000000000001</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-04-08T23:43:37.573242200Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>4828</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation ActivityID="{f00f00-f00-f00-f00-f00f00f00f00}" /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="7512" ThreadID="3220" /> 
  <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2/Operational</Channel> 
  <Computer>Matt-Seven</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-f00-f00-f00-f00f00f00-f00f00f00-f00f00f00-f00f00" /> 
  </System>
 <UserData>
 <CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy>
  <Policy type="CERT_CHAIN_POLICY_SSL" constant="4" /> 
  <Certificate fileRef="f00f00f00f00f00f00f00f00f00f00f00.cer" subjectName="www.example.com" /> 
  <CertificateChain chainRef="{f00f00-f00-f00-f00-f00f00f00f00}" /> 
  <Flags value="0" /> 
 <SSLAdditionalPolicyInfo authType="server" serverName="example.com">
  <IgnoreFlags value="0" /> 
  </SSLAdditionalPolicyInfo>
  <Status chainIndex="0" elementIndex="0" /> 
  <EventAuxInfo ProcessName="iexplore.exe" /> 
  <CorrelationAuxInfo TaskId="{f00f00-f00-f00-f00-f00f00f00f00}" SeqNumber="4" /> 
  <Result value="800B010F">The certificate's CN name does not match the passed value.</Result> 
  </CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy>
  </UserData>
  </Event>
```

Numeric values from my event log replaced with f00.

Comment: I believe now it has something to do with the way namespaces impact XPATH queries.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950779.aspx

Comment: Okay, adding `XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(evtASxml.NameTable); ns.AddNamespace("foo", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event");` and using `evtASxml.SelectSingleNode(@"//foo:Result/@value",ns).Value` works as expected. Namespaces seem pretty inelegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing, but I think you want `//*[@value]`, and not `//@value`

[image]

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(evtASxml.SelectSingleNode(@"//@serverName").Value` was working fine for me, where there was only one attribte wih that name.

Comment: Wonderful tool you've built there Cheeso! I must have used XPath Visualizer a million times. Oh! And .NET Zip too :D

Comment: Is there a way to get my code to act like xpath visualizer does with the default ns?

Comment: I don't know *a good way*, Matt. The way the tool does it is a bloody hack - it actually parses the string and inserts namespace prefixes in every place it thinks appropriate. It's not perfect, though, and it does break in some edge cases. But if your xpath is not going to be complex then that quick/dirty approach may be what you want. If so, see https://xpathvisualizer.svn.codeplex.com/svn/XPathVisualizer/Tool/XPathVisualizerTool.cs and look for the FixupXpathExpressionWithDefaultNamespace method.

Comment: Adding the prefixes to my xpath statements isn't too too bad, since I only have a handful that I need for my application. I found quite a bit of grumbling online about XML namespaces, and it made me feel a good deal better to know I'm not the only one who had an issue.

Comment: @Matt: The explanation of the problem and the best way to approach it in C# is contained in my answer. Please, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

**The reason for this problem is that the XML document is in a default namespace**.

Selecting elements by name when they are in a default namespace is the most FAQ in XPath.

Xpath treats any unprefixed element name as belonging to "no namespace". In your case no `Result` element exists that is in "no namespace" (all elements are in the "http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event" namespace) and thus no node is selected.

**In C# it is recommended that you provide an XmlNamespaceManager as the second argument of `SelectSingleNode()` -- just use [the appropriate overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b.aspx)**.

Use:

```
evtASxml.SelectSingleNode(@"//x:Result/@value", yourXmlNamespaceManager).Value
```

where  the association of `"x"` to  the "http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event" namespace has been added to `yourXmlNamespaceManager` using the **[`AddNamespace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.addnamespace.aspx)** method.